# C++ WM_SIZE for minimum application size

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use the WM_SIZE event to force the application to be of a minimum size, the code:

```
  case WM_SIZE:
   int nWidth;
   int nHeight;
   int _dWidth;
   int _dHeight;       
   _dWidth  = 870;
    _dHeight = 510; 
   nWidth  = LOWORD(lParam);
   nHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
   if (nWidth <= _dWidth){
    return 0;
   }
   else if (nHeight <= _dHeight) {
    return 0;
   }
```

apparently I have to return 0 if I process this message but doing so has no effect as the application can still be made smaller but it also disables the close button on the application so what is the correct way to have an application that can be resized but having a minimum size?

Comment: WM_SIZING, not WM_SIZE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to handle that is to implement an handler for the [WM_GETMINMAXINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

When receiving that message you can fill in the fields of a structure to provide minimum and maximum acceptable size for your window. The limitations will be properly handled by the window manager when interacting with the user.

The `WM_SIZE` is meant to be a one-directional **notification**, not something you can negotiate with. You are expected to simply invalidate your layout or window content.